# if/else statement for onclick javascript:sendURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, getelementbyid

I have the following code for creating a simple drop down nav. However, this is based on if a value is selected and the GO button will take the user to the link. I would like to put an if/else statement so if no value is selected, GO button will default to 1st link.

```
<script>
    function sendURL(url,obj) {
        document.getElementById("urlhidden").value = url;
        jQuery('.current').html(obj.parentNode.innerHTML);
    }
    function submitURL() {
        document.location = document.getElementById("urlhidden").value;
    }
</script>


<form name="navigate" class="select">
    <ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="urlhidden" id="urlhidden" />                 
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:sendURL('<?php $link = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/node/';echo $link?>4',this)">link1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:sendURL('<?php $link = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/node/';echo $link?>5',this)">link2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="btnHolderInline">
        <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:submitURL();"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's much easier if you do this in script rather than inline with the html element.

Comment: `javascript:` is only needed in `href` attributes. In an `onclick`, you're already in "JavaScript mode".

Comment: Please post the actual HTML that the browser receives, not the PHP.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery UI dropdowns? jQuery UI can give you the same slick look with much less effort.

Comment: the code wasn't written by me, it was written by a contract developer who is not welling to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look very "simple" to me. What's wrong with a "traditional" drop-down nav?

```
<form action="javascript:location.href=this.page.options[this.page.selectedIndex].value">
    <select name="page">
        <option value="somepage.php">link1</option>
        <option value="otherpage.php">link2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

That aside, the problem with your original code is that you don't appear to have any `.current` element. Really what you want is something like:

```
function submitURL() {
    $(this).parent("form").find("a:eq(0)").click();
}
```